# :last for table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  <table>

    <tr><td>First Row</td><td>2 Row</td><td>1 last</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Middle Row</td><td>2 Row</td><td>2 last</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Last Row</td><td>2 Row</td><td>3 last</td></tr>

  </table>


$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $("td:last").css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
  });
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/DxVG5/1/

why this working only for 3 last, but on 1 last and 2 last no? how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you know what exactly "last" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the context of the td, you're already in a for loop so the 'this' variable can be used. In this context 'this' is equal to the tr you're currently iterating on.

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $("td:last",this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example will get the last `td` in each `tr` because using :last literally gets the last `td` in the `table`.  Try this instead:

```
$('tr td:last-child').css({
   backgroundColor: 'yellow', 
   fontWeight: 'bolder'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the context in which that `TD` is the last one. In your case which `TR`. Passing the second argument to the jQuery constructor should do it.

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    // ------------|
    //             | here
    $("td:last", this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $("td:last-child").css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/DxVG5/11/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are only looking through `TD`s inside the current `TR`, by using `$(this).find()` or by adding `this` as the second argument in your selector.

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
  $("td:last",this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nslr/DxVG5/4/

You were checking for the global `$('td:last')`, not the one for the specific row, which is done like this (inside the `.each()`)

```
$(this).find('td:last')....
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign `last-child` of the `tr`

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
    $("td:last-child").css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
  });
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ucCQH/5/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('tr').each(function(index) {
   $("td:last", this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
});
```